# Redis - How the key HASH and SET and ZSET are related on the CrudRepository save?

Tags: java, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am new to Redis and developing code using `Spring Boot + Spring Data Redis` example. When I saved the records, I see KEYS gets created and out of these keys `4 are HASH`, `1 ZSET` and `all others are SET`.

I did not see in the Spring docs, meaning of each KEY is getting saved.  .

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
 1) "persons:c5cfd49d-6688-4b83-a9b7-be55dd1c36ad"
 2) "persons:firstname:bran"
 3) "persons:39e14dae-fa23-4935-948f-1922d668d1c2"
 4) "persons:f0b6dd26-8922-4a36-bd2a-792a17dddff7"
 5) "persons:address.city:Achalpur"
 6) "persons:e493385a-64ae-42be-8398-51757153d273:idx"
 7) "persons:053cdfea-e430-4e1c-acbd-ac40050b10cd:idx"
 8) "persons:firstname:rickon"
 9) "persons:e493385a-64ae-42be-8398-51757153d273"
10) "persons:address.country:India"
11) "persons:e7fc3ebe-9b48-48a8-a5f4-33a0e21f782f:idx"
12) "persons:firstname:sansa"
13) "persons:address:location"
14) "persons:firstname:robb"
15) "persons:firstname:jon"
16) "persons:lastname:snow"
17) "persons:e7fc3ebe-9b48-48a8-a5f4-33a0e21f782f"
18) "persons:c5cfd49d-6688-4b83-a9b7-be55dd1c36ad:idx"
19) "persons:lastname:stark"
20) "persons:f0b6dd26-8922-4a36-bd2a-792a17dddff7:idx"
21) "persons:053cdfea-e430-4e1c-acbd-ac40050b10cd"
22) "persons:39e14dae-fa23-4935-948f-1922d668d1c2:idx"
23) "persons:firstname:arya"
24) "persons:83cd4f58-c272-4d81-9023-8c66c8ac34b0:idx"
25) "persons:83cd4f58-c272-4d81-9023-8c66c8ac34b0"
26) "persons:address.city:Nagpur"
27) "persons:firstname:eddard"
28) "persons"
```

[image]

Person.java

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "children" })
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@RedisHash("persons")
public class Person {

    private @Id String id;
    private @Indexed String firstname;
    private @Indexed String lastname;

    private Gender gender;
    private Address address;

    private @Reference List<Person> children;
}
```

Address.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Address {

    private @Indexed String city;
    private @Indexed String country;
    private @GeoIndexed Point location;
}
```

Gender.java

```
public enum Gender {
    FEMALE, MALE
}
```

RedisExampleBootApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RedisExampleBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired PersonRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisExampleBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {  
        Address address1 = Address.builder().city("the north").country("winterfell").location(new Point(52.9541053, -1.2401016)).build();
        Address address2 = Address.builder().city("Casterlystein").country("Westerland").location(new Point(51.5287352, -0.3817819)).build();

        Person eddard = Person.builder().firstname("eddard").lastname("stark").gender(Gender.MALE).address(address1).build();
        Person robb = Person.builder().firstname("robb").lastname("stark").gender(Gender.MALE).address(address2).build();
        Person sansa = Person.builder().firstname("sansa").lastname("stark").gender(Gender.FEMALE).address(address1).build();
        Person arya = Person.builder().firstname("arya").lastname("stark").gender(Gender.FEMALE).address(address2).build();
        Person bran = Person.builder().firstname("bran").lastname("stark").gender(Gender.MALE).address(address1).build();
        Person rickon = Person.builder().firstname("rickon").lastname("stark").gender(Gender.MALE).address(address2).build();
        Person jon = Person.builder().firstname("jon").lastname("snow").gender(Gender.MALE).address(address1).build();

        repository.save(eddard);
        repository.save(robb);
        repository.save(sansa);
        repository.save(arya);
        repository.save(bran);
        repository.save(rickon);
        repository.save(jon);

        List<Person> starks = repository.findByLastname(eddard.getLastname());
        System.out.println("Person ="+starks.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering, do you mind sharing your RedisTemplate implementation code? (Or this is generated by @RedisHash annotation?) I am new to Spring-Data-Redis myself and didn't know of the @RedisHash annotation and want to check it out.

Anyways, essentially what is happening here is that Spring-Data-Redis repository is inserting the Person object in different data structures natively supported by Redis for different purposes.

Redis supports different data structures such as:

1. Hash
   Redis creates a map of string fields and string values to represent your entire Person object.
   If you do `HGETALL persons:{your person id}` it will show all the different fields and values associated with your person Object

   `HASH holding property values for id "c5cfd49d-6688-4b83-a9b7-be55dd1c36ad" in keyspace "persons"`
2. Set
   Redis inserts the basic raw string and indexes entities based on their field. Hence there were a lot `SET` operations in your Redis DB. You can see indexes of `firstName` and `lastName` in your data set

   `SET holding all ids known in the keyspace "persons"`
3. ZSet
   This is Redis operation for `Sorted Sets` data structure. Which is an ordered collections of strings.
   From Redis Documentations

   `In short with sorted sets you can do a lot of tasks with great performance that are really hard to model in other kind of databases.`

Seems like Spring Data automatically inserts the location data as a sorted set to optimize CRUD operations.

You can read more here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/redis/repositories/README.md

https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: Hi thank you for posting.

I have better idea for my own code improvements now.

Sorry, but I thought your question was why did the CrudRepository performed a lot of different kind of insertion operations?

Maybe If i have better understanding of your concern I can modify the answer?

Thank you

Comment: This is also part of my concern - "why did the CrudRepository performed a lot of different kind of insertion operations?"

Comment: Ah I see...

Essentially, Spring-Data-Redis does a lot of optimization to ensure that the CRUD operation can be done quickly. In this case, because you added `@Indexed` annotation to your Person fields, it automatically does `SET` commands to do secondary indexing. 

I believe that if your class is very simple no other annotations attached to it. The repository will not do as much operations but probably only does `HSET` to insert the data into redis.. You can see that you used a lot of `@indexed` and `@GeoIndexed`. These forces the repository to do more operations for you

Comment: Ok Thanks. I just wanted to ask generic question. I am looking to move Postgres to Redis - I almost have static data around 5K records only. But while converting JPA to Redis Entity, I am not sure how to maintain the Many-To-Many - bi-directional with join table and Many-To-One relationship ? I simply thought of removing all annotations and keep the POJO as simple as possible. Now How to take care of join-table. Could you please let me know how to model data and how to learn more about redis? I dont see good material over web

Comment: Also, how to make the use of `@Reference`, because same private `@Reference List<Person> children;` object use in the same Person class

Comment: With regards to moving Data from Postgres to Redis. I think its not the right choice of system.

Redis has no relational relationship between the data. In essence, you can't do complex queries with JOIN and all that.

Redis is most popular to use as Cache or simple temporary data storage before moving the data permanently into a Relational or NoSQL DB.

And with regards to `@Reference`. https://docs.oasis-open.org/opencsa/sca-j/javadoc/org/oasisopen/sca/annotation/Reference.html Can look more into this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183287/discussion-between-paa-and-jwiryo).